# trigram index on jsonb field does not work?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have created index like this (`documentData` column is of type `jsonb`):

```
CREATE INDEX trgm_idx 
ON "Documents" 
USING gin (cast(("documentData"#>'{text1}') AS text) gin_trgm_ops);
```

Now when I am executing following query:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE 
SELECT "documentData"#>'{text1}' 
FROM "Documents" 
WHERE cast("documentData"#>'{text1}' as text) % 'abc'
```

I get following output

```
Seq Scan on "Documents"  (cost=0.00..1.08 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=2.116..2.116 rows=0 loops=1)
  Filter: ((("documentData" #> '{text1}'::text[]))::text % 'abc'::text)
  Rows Removed by Filter: 20
Planning time: 9.645 ms
Execution time: 4.877 ms
```

Why query is not using trigram index?

Comment: How many rows does the table `documents` contain?

Comment: there are 20 rows in the table

Comment: For such a tiny number of rows, Postgres will never use an index. A seq scan will always be faster.

Comment: *Off*: your query could be more readably if you would use `"documentData" ->> 'text1'` instead of `cast("documentData"#>'{text1}' as text)` (they mean almost the same -- the difference is `->>` won't convert object and array types to text, which is preferable, if you want to search them with trigram)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name how many rows I need to see that PG is using index?

Comment: To answer how many rows would be required is nigh on impossible to answer, the query planner will decide whether or not to do an index scan based on several variables, such as the cost of a hard drive seek, known table statistics on the regularity of a value in the table, function cost and so on. For a rough rule of thumb if you are trying to retrieve 1% or less from the table then an index will be used. On a really small table like that a sequential scan across 20 rows is not such a bad thing.

Comment: @pozs I haved checked what you said about `->>` operator and it seems that it casts arrays/objects to text too. For example: `SELECT ('{"arr":[1,2,3]}'::jsonb)->>'arr'` returns string (text) `'[1,2,3]'` so I am not sure what is the difference? Also `->>` does not allow to query for nested attributes.

Comment: @user606521 yeah, my bad; but my point is, if you use the double greater-than ended operators (in your case `#>>` then) you don't need an additional cast